# Vanilla JS Ajax and base64img issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, base64

I am encoding an image using a function that uses a canvas element to encode an image to base64.
Then I try to post the Base64 string through AJAX to my php `ajax_controller`:

```
function submitParticipation(name,email,phone,city) {
    encodeImage(uploadedImg, function(encodedImage) { 
        uploadedImg = encodedImage;
    });

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = 'uid='+ facebookUserId + '&name=' + name  + '&email=' + email +
        '&phone=' + phone + '&city=' + city + '&img_string=' + base64Img +
        '&facebook_name=' + facebookUserFullName + '&facebook_pic=' +
         facebookProfilePic + '&facebook_email=' + facebookUserEmail;

    ajax.open("POST", "main_ajax_controller.php?m=store_participation", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send(params);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            var response = ajax.responseText;
        }            //If an error occur during the ajax call.
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 404) {

        }
    }
}
```

The `base64Img` though does not go through the AJAX call - it goes through empty.

Any idea why?

The base64Img variable is defined just fine - I can see this because I log it in the console right before defining it in the `params` variable of the Ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your params string is invalid because you don't encode each of the values. All of them, including the base64 value should be wrapped in `encodeURIComponent()`.

For example:

```
base64Img = encodeURIComponent(base64Img);
```

Base64 values include an `=` character, which is breaking the key pair string.

Comment: why do the rest of the params need this then, if it's just the base64 '=' that's breaking this?

Comment: Other special characters (not just `=` and `&`) need to be encoded in order to comply with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` standard format. Even if you believe there will be no special characters in the values, it's still good practice to encode anyway.